# Pylint says 'string' module is deprecated. What's the new way to get range of lowercase characters?

Tags: python, pylint

I was just pylinting some code and noticed a colleague had imported the old Python 'string' module, not to use any functions from it but simply to have access to the constant '**string.lowercase**'.

I removed the deprecated import and substituted 'abcdef...' for string.lowercase, but I was wondering: is there a better way I should be doing this?

Comment: Or you could use something like: `[chr(i) for i in range(97,123)]`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`string` itself is not deprecated, just those methods like `string.join` that are better accessed through a string object. You can still import `string`, and get `string.ascii_lowercase` for what you want.

pylint's reporting this as an error is a known bug - see http://www.logilab.org/ticket/2481.

Comment: Interesting. I'm aware of the replacement of string functions with string methods, but pylint marks any importing of 'string' as a error itself. A bug in pylint perhaps?

Comment: Does it flag importing of specific names, like `from string import ascii_lowercase` also?

Comment: Yes. pylint still return `Uses of a deprecated module 'string'` with `from string import ascii_lowercase`.

Comment: That is a bug in pylint then.

Comment: A little research shows you're right: http://www.logilab.org/ticket/2481 . If you add this link to your answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I didn't come back for 10 years, but I see you did add a link to your answer so I have now marked it as correct.